# .net version 6.0.300 Optimizing assemblies for performance is not supported for the selected target platform or architecture

Tags: .net, azure-devops, continuous-integration

When migrating from .net 5 to .net 6 I run into similar issue as described here https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/24269, except in my case the build fails with NETSDK1095, instead of just printing warning. I pinned version to `6.0.201` with global.json. I was able to observe mentioned issue with version `6.0.300` on my local machine. With pinned version it went away. Assuming version `6.0.201` does not suffer mentioned regression.

I added step to install custom SDK in to the azure pipeline. 
Than `dotnet --version` command prints out `6.0.201`

Original pipeline looks like this

- `dotnet restore`
- `dotnet build -c Release --no-restore`
- `dotnet test`
- `dotnet publish -c Release --no-build -r "win10-x64" -p:PublishReadyToRun=true`

And it is `PublishReadyToRun=true` which is causing an issue. When I added `--self-contained` it fixed it on `6.0.201` on localhost, but still fails in the pipe

It fails with error:

`C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\6.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(293,5): error NETSDK1095: Optimizing assemblies for performance is not supported for the selected target platform or architecture. Please verify you are using a supported runtime identifier, or set the PublishReadyToRun property to false.`

I ran it on `windows-2019` and `windows-2022` azure agents.

Anybody knows how to temporarily fix this issue?

Comment: The issue you link to is about a different error. Please verify your link.

Comment: this is same problem I'm having https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/24269#issuecomment-1123103775

Comment: That issue is about NETSDK1179. You appear to have error NETSDK1095. I don't see how they are related.

Comment: right, i changed the question

Comment: i found the solution in here, thanks for highlighting it's different issue
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62219#issuecomment-984249404

Answer (score 0):

Try publishing with `-p:PublishReadyToRun=false`